# JSON POST using RestAssured

Tags: java, rest-assured

I am trying to create a test to validate the response of a JSON Post is as expected.

I am trying to test the POST of a JSON message body to a URL which is turn then sends a text message and if successful it sends a response that it was successful again in JSON format.

My test is as follows

```
public void simpleTest() {

      String myJson = "{\"phoneNumber\":\"353837986524\", \"messageContent\":\"test\"}";
      given()
              .port(31111) // port number
              .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
              .body(myJson)
              .when()
              .post("/testenvironment/text/send")
              .then().assertThat()
              .body("message", equalTo("{\"resultMessage\":\"Message accepted\"}"));
  }
```

But seem to be getting this exception

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You can either send form parameters
>   OR body content in POST, not both!

And I'm not sure what the issue is?

Comment: Please don't change the intent of your question, as it invalidates answers. If you're having trouble implementing an answer, post a comment on it, and the answerer will receive a notification. If you end up with another question, then post it as a __new question__. You can link back here for context.

Answer (score 14):

Restassured is failing to parse Json as per the stack trace. I use [org.json](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20151123) jar, which is more elegant way to handle big json inputs. There are other implementations of json handling in java, which can be used based on your preference.

Coming to your code:

```
public void simpleTest() {

   // use org.json JSONObject to define your json
   JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject()
                             .put("phoneNumber","353837986524")
                             .put("messageContent","test");

   given()
      .port(31111) // port number
      .contentType("application/json")  //another way to specify content type
      .body(jsonObj.toString())   // use jsonObj toString method
   .when()
      .post("/testenvironment/text/send")
   .then()
      .assertThat()
      .body("message", equalTo("{\"resultMessage\":\"Message accepted\"}"));
}
```

Also, I didnt find what the output of the rest service in the question. For example it is returning a a json `{"resultMessage":"Message accepted"}`  you should be validating the response in the following way:

```
...
.body("resultMessage",equalTo("Message accepted"));
```

Comment: Thanks but I still get the same error `groovy.json.JsonException: Lexing failed on line: 1, column: 1, while reading 'R', no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized.` I will create a new question as my original one was different and it has edited

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the mimeType to a header instead of a parameter.

And based on the information you shared I think what you need is the Content-Type header, not mimeType.

Comment: This springs another exception `groovy.json.JsonException: Lexing failed on line: 1, column: 1, while reading 'R', no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized.`

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace print of the above exception or is above the only message you can see? Seems to be a JSON parsing error.

Comment: Just to confirm are you still using mimeType header or did you also change it to Content-Type as per my answer?

Comment: yes it's `.header("Content-Type", "application/json")` i'll update question

Comment: I think it might be better to create a separate question for the new exception maybe?